# ASP.NET use Proxy value in asp:GridView

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a asp:GridView, in one column I have

```
<asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="Created" ItemStyle-Wrap="false">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkTimeline" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Continue" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' Text='<%# CreatedAt_Proxy %>'></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

and the Proxy:

```
public string CreatedAt_Proxy
{
    get
    {
        string rv = "";
        int secondsPast = (int)DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(CreatedAt).TotalSeconds;
        int threshold = 5 * 24 * 60 * 60;
        if (secondsPast >= threshold) rv = "<span style='color: red'>";
        rv += E.HourFormat(secondsPast, false) + " ago";
        rv += "<br />" + CreatedAt.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
        if (secondsPast >= threshold) rv += "</span>";
        return rv;
    }
}
```

I want to use that proxy in may gridview (`Text='<%# CreatedAt_Proxy %>'`) so that i can generate links with the text containing different times.

Answer (score 0):

You hook into RowDataBound event to render the data as you like.

```
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        LinkButton lnkTimelineButton = e.Row.FindControl("lnkTimeline") as LinkButton ;
        lnkTimelineButton.Text= GetProxyTime();
    }
```

//    Create the below function and get the values for proxytime.

```
    private string GetProxyTime()
    {
     string rv = "";
                    int secondsPast = (int)DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(CreatedAt).TotalSeconds;
                    int threshold = 5 * 24 * 60 * 60;
                    if (secondsPast >= threshold) rv = "<span style='color: red'>";
                    rv += E.HourFormat(secondsPast, false) + " ago";
                    rv += "<br />" + CreatedAt.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
                    if (secondsPast >= threshold) rv += "</span>";
                    return rv;
    }
```